# How can i update an entity object (detach) in EF CF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, detach

I find out the solution:

```
MyEntity tmp = ctx.Entities.Where<MyEntity>(t => t.Id == objectWithNewValues.Id).SingleOrDefault();
if (tmp != null)
{
    var entityInDb = ctx.Entry(tmp);
    entityInDb.CurrentValues.SetValues(objectWithNewValues);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException ...
}
```

Before i used EF4, generate code from schema, the context will have an method
"context.ApplyCurrentValue(entity)"

when i try to update a detach object, i can do:

```
void UpdateObject(Entity e)
{    
     Entity tmp = ctx.Entities.Where(t=>t.id ==e.id);
     ctx.ApplyCurrentValue(e);
     ctx.SaveChannges();
}
```

Now I have a project using EF4 code first approach and I cannot find "ApplyCurrentValue" method anymore.

so how can I do the update action?

Entity class is a very simple class

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

my context is a also a very simple class inherte the DBContext

```
public MyContext : DBContext
{
    public DBSet<MyEntity> Entities {get;set}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("tblMyEntity");
    }
}
```

And i am trying to do something as below. but value didnt get update into database!

```
ctx.entities.Attach(entity);
var entityInDb = ctx.Entry(entity);
entityInDb.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

How can i do the update?

Answer (score 6):

late reply, but i think it will help community.
change your update method to this

```
ctx.entities.Attach(entity);
var entry= ctx.Entry(entity);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ApplyChanges method might be what you're after:

```
model.ApplyChanges("Objects", object);
model.SaveChanges();
object.AcceptChanges();
```

**Note:** we're using the self-tracking entities T4 templates in our EF4 service

Comment: i am not using self-tracking entities.... hmmm....but the ApplyChanges method should come from the context.. it should matter what kind of entity we are using... what type of conext are u using?

Comment: Hmm, I did some digging and the "ApplyChanges" method is an extension method that comes with the self-tracking entities template. It handles the "tracking" of the entity during the update. Apologies then, I will dig around a bit more.

Comment: It's not without its quirks, but it does help a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Attach method will help? Take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx) for more information.

```
void UpdateObject(Entity e) {
  Entity tmp = ctx.Entities.Attach(e);
  ctx.SaveChannges();
}
```